# Translate objects relative to the camera view

Tags: c++, math, matrix-multiplication, glm-math

I'm trying to translate objects via matrices in OpenGL and I know how to rotate/translate/scale objects in model coordinates. 
[image]

However, I want to make a callback to translate objects relative to the camera view (so, the z-axis always looks at the camera): 
[image]

I'm operating with objects using the MVP matrix. Does somebody know how to translate objects on the screen coordinates, not world ones?

Answer (score 1):

So you have this sequence of matrices: `project * view * model * <vertices>`.

Going right-to-left:

- `model` converts the model from model space to world space.
- `view` converts it from world space to camera space.
- `project` converts it from camera space to [clip space](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Transformation).

You have your offset in camera space, and want to convert it to model space, so you need to apply:

- `view.inverse()` to transform from camera space to world space.
- `model.inverse()` to transform from world space to model space.

Those are too ordered right-to-left, so:

```
modelspace_offset = model.inverse() * view.inverse() * cameraspace_offset
```

Comment: Suggestion: I'd bet OP probably also wants the viewport transform, to work in pixels, not clip coords.

Comment: @imallett Hmm. True, but off the top of my head I can't remember how to do this conversion when perspective is involved.

Comment: The nice thing about the projection matrix is that it abstracts that detail, so it doesn't matter. The viewport transform is just a scale+bias. The only complicating factor is the perspective divide in the middle (ref. converting clip to screen many many places on SO for deets).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, how can I find cameraspace_offset?

Comment: @Dark_Phoenix I thought you already have it? It's the desired movement relative to the camera view (with Z=0, if you don't want to move away or towards the viewer).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I have only the world matrix (use as model matrix), view matrix (camera location), and projection matrix (perspective). And I don't know how to translate world coordinates such as I just translate an object on screen coordinates

Comment: @Dark_Phoenix So your offset is measured in pixels, not in whatever units you use in GL?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, in units

Comment: @Dark_Phoenix Then I don't understand what the problem is. `cameraspace_offset` *is* your offset.